# What were the breaking changes to ember testing when emberjs v1 got released?

Tags: ember.js, ember-testing

I had a suite of qunit integration tests that were running fine in rc6. I made the upgrade to 1.0 and now the tests are giving me the run-loop error. What changes occurred from rc6 to v1 that would break these tests? I can't spot anything from the ember blogs.

Comment: In the ember blog http://emberjs.com/blog/, is created a new post when a new version is released, describing the changes.

Comment: Thanks. I did check blogs but didn't spot anything immediate to break my test. Of course my post is a bit lazy, I apologize. I didn't want to go through my code and wrap lots of things in Em.run, so wanted to ask the community before I did anything silly.